# JSF 2.1 + Tomcat 8 - error in deploying

Tags: xml, maven, jsf, tomcat, netbeans

I have a problem in deploying my simple Java EE app with Tomcat.
I get a few exceptions like this below:

```
...
09-Nov-2014 14:06:36.541 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\webapps\app.war
09-Nov-2014 14:06:37.197 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/app]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1703)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2450)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:852)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1262)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1145)
    at com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer.<clinit>(FacesInitializer.java:106)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:181)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:151)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1599)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5120)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more

09-Nov-2014 14:06:37.197 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\webapps\app.war
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/app]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1703)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

09-Nov-2014 14:06:37.228 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\webapps\app.war has finished in 656 ms
09-Nov-2014 14:06:37.228 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\webapps\docs
...
```

Here is my `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My `faces-config.xml` file is empty.

What is wrong with my project? I use NetBeans 8.0 and apache-maven-3.2.3.

Comment: Sorry, do you deploy your application with Eclipse?

Comment: No, with NetBeans... Why are you asking?

Comment: I asked you because I use Eclipse. Anyway doing a quick search on Google seems that this problem is relating to your dependencies inside project's pom file, can you post it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my `pom.xml`

```
<groupId>com.karol</groupId>
<artifactId>jsf2tut</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>jsf2tut</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.29</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.29</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>app</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```